# How to draw String in real-time game with zero object allocation in Android?

Tags: android, real-time

I'm writing real-time game in Android and I'd like to do not allocate any object in main loop. The problem is `String` value for score.

I have class, that implements `CharSequence` and uses `StringBuilder`:

```
public class MyString implements CharSequence {

    protected String prefix;
    protected StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    public MyString(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(prefix);
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        removeValue();
        stringBuilder.append(value);
    }

    public void setValue(float value) {
        removeValue();
        stringBuilder.append(value);
    }

    private void removeValue() {
        if (prefix == null) {
            stringBuilder.setLength(0);
        } else {
            stringBuilder.setLength(prefix.length());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public char charAt(int index) {
        return stringBuilder.charAt(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int length() {
        return stringBuilder.length();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
        return null; // not necessary
    }

}
```

The usage of this class is:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
MyString myString = new MyString("Your score: ");

// Main loop
while(true) {
    myString.setValue(Game.score);
    canvas.drawText(myString, 0, myString.length(), 0, 0, paint);
}
```

The problem is, that `StringBuilder.append(int)` creates `String` object (by `String.valueOf(int)`) every iteration.

What is your way to solve a problem like this?

My next thought was to convert `int` and `float` to array of chars and the `setValue()` methods would add this array into `StringBuilder`. The array would be stored in `MyString` class and it would be created only once and then would be reused. But I can't find way, how to convert `float` correctly into array of chars. The `int` is not problem.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some C# code that I wrote for exactly this purpose. It should be pretty simple to convert this to Java. The `minDigits` parameter causes zero-padding on the left -- You can skip that if you like.

```
// drawInteger doesn't allocate like string.Format()
int[] digitBuff = new int[10];
string[] digits = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

void drawInteger(SpriteFont font, int i, int minDigits, Vector2 pos, Color colour) {
    Debug.Assert(i >= 0 && minDigits > 0 && minDigits <= digitBuff.Length);
    int index = 0;
    while (i > 0 || index < minDigits) {
        digitBuff[index] = i % 10;
        i /= 10;
        ++index;
    }
    while (index > 0) {
        --index;
        string digit = digits[digitBuff[index]];
        sb.DrawString(font, digit, pos, colour);
        pos.X += font.MeasureString(digit).X;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this answer is acceptable. I wrote similar function to convert `int` to `char[]`. But, do you know a way to draw `float` number? I'm getting bad precision with `float`. `Double` is OK.

Comment: For floats I'd suggest multiplying by pow(10, precision), rounding to an integer, then doing the same process, drawing the decimal point at the appropriate place. The minDigits parameter would be useful here as it would need to be at least precision+1 to handle numbers smaller than 1. You could handle negative N by drawing the "-" followed by -N.

Comment: I'm doing it the same way as you suggested. But I'm getting bad results for some numbers. Never mind, `double` is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a blitting approach:
Pre render your "Your Score: " as a drawable.
Then make drables for each digit 0-9.
In the main loop you can build your score field by drawing the numbers needed to another drawble. 
I am not sure this will be faster, but you will not need to create any new objects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But your approach just change the way of drawing from drawing `String` to drawing drawables. It could be faster (I did not test it), but the problem is still there. How will I know, which drawables (from 0-9) should I use to draw the number of score? I just know the score as `int` or `float` and it could be e.g. 2341.